# on update method getting error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to perform UPDATE operation but getting error `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. Getting this error when I press the UPDATE button for data update. I can not understand the error reason. Please help!!!

controller block update method

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $book = Book::find($id);
        $book -> BookName = $request->get('NBookName');
        $book -> BookID = $request->get('NBookId');
        $book -> BookUnitPrice = $request->get('NBookUnitPrice');
        if($book->save())
            {
                return view('pages.book', $this->fetchData())->with('alert-success', 'books updated successfully.');
            }  
            else
            {
                return redirect()->back()->with('alert-success',$error->getMessage()); 
            }
    }
```

update page

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{action('BookController@update', $id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH"/>


        <div class="row" style="padding-left: 1%;">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Book Name</label><span class="required">*</span>
                        <input type="text" value="{{$book->BookName}}" maxlength="100" minlength="3" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" required="required" name="NBookName" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5%;">
                        <label>Book ID</label><span class="required">*</span>
                        <input type="text" value="{{$book->BookID}}" maxlength="10" minlength="1" autocomplete="off" required="required" name="NBookId" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5%;">
                        <label>Unit Price</label><span class="required">*</span>
                        <input type="text" value="{{$book->BookUnitPrice}}" maxlength="5" required="required" autocomplete="off" runat="server" name="NBookUnitPrice" class="form-control" onkeypress="return decimalOnly(event)"/>
                    </div>                                   
                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5%;">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>        
                    </div>                                      
                </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Route list

```
// for books
Route::get('/book','BookController@create');
Route::post('/book','BookController@store');
Route::get('/book/{id}','BookController@edit');
Route::patch('/book/{id}', 'BookController@update');
```

***I updated the route method from `PUT` to `PATCH`, it worked. Now the data is updating. But the success message in UPDATE is not printing.*** Please help!!!
Please see the image attached for the error page. 
[image]

Comment: can you add your route list ?

Comment: added route list

Comment: see, you have no route defined with name `pages.book` and you are using it in redirect. causing you error. Where do you want to redirect after success ?

Comment: please change the input value PATCH to PUT will work

Comment: @rkj please see my updated code for `UPDATE` method. I can now update the data but the success message is not printing in `pages. book` page. Please help!

Comment: @rkj you have a good point but would that trigger the MethodNotAllowedHttpException error?

Comment: he changes his code, so no point of that now

Comment: @rkj why I am not getting the message? You've removed your comment too. Please help!!!! Thank You!!!

Comment: this is now a different question

Comment: @lagbox ok it might be a different question now but what could be the cause of this problem and how can I solve it? Please can you reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to change

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH"/>
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
```

or change

```
Route::put('/book/{id}', 'BookController@update');
```

to

```
Route::patch('/book/{id}', 'BookController@update');
```

Comment: I changed the value from "PATCH" to "PUT" but still getting the same error.

Comment: Run `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`. I don't see any error in your code after your update.

Comment: please see my updated code for `UPDATE` method. I can now update the data but the success message is not printing in `pages. book` page. Please help!

Comment: For your next problem, have a look at what @rkj tells you right under your question. You are mixing up routes with named routes.

Comment: I am just learning laravel and the things here are getting complex. You are telling the solution to my next problem is already answered but you have put the question on that reply too. Is there any way simple solution of my problem?

Comment: ok my friend, try this `return view('pages.book', compact('book'))->with(['success' => 'books updated successfully.']);`. In your view, the data is accessible as $book and your message will be shown on top. It's an array. Possible message are success and error. You can add more. Have a look at your resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php file. You will find the success/error notifications there.

Comment: Laravel may be overwhelming at first. You'll be fine. It all clicks together later on. It's worth your time. Promise.

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey well put

Comment: why not to use Route::resource for such things? Update method will be fired in both request methods! You should to look into laracast videos or "laravel cookbook"
and you'll get: 
PUT|PATCH                              | api/users/{user}                                            | users.update